# Installing Fedora on a PC with Ubuntu and Windows 7

Tags: fedora

I understand, I don't want to overload with three OS. But, my ISP's Debian driver is not supported on Ubuntu 10.10. Today I downloaded Fedora and want to give it a try. If everything works, I will uninstall Ubuntu.

Is it possible to install Fedora with Ubuntu and Windows 7 already there? Fedora supports debian-i386 drivers or not?

Comment: Why not just install Debian?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the driver didn't work on Ubuntu, forget about Fedora.
For two reason:
- RPM format. Fedora uses RPM. You have to fiddle with it to get that installed.
- Bleeding-edge. Fedora ships the VERY latest software. I guess the reason it didn't work on Ubuntu because the kernel / userland software is newer.

In short, forget about it. Just use Windows and Debian if you want to use linux that much.